# File appearing as 'File not found' when using php suffix for file name

Tags: nginx

I looked for resources online but couldn't find anything.

If I enter the url..

```
https://10.5.9.10:8460/helloworld
```

It will work fine and dandy.

The moment I enter the url...

```
https://10.5.9.10:8460/helloworld.php
```

It will return with a 'File Not Found'.

The nginx config is as follows...

```
listen                192.168.1.1:12000;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/webapp/access.log combined;
error_log             /var/log/nginx/webapp/error.log warn;

charset               utf-8;
index                 index.php;
root                  /opt/webapp/www;
keepalive_timeout     10;

location / {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}

location /images/ {
    alias                  /opt/webapp/www/images/stuff/;
}

location /css/ {
    alias                  /opt/webapp/www/css/stuff/;
}

fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass      127.0.0.1:8000;
    fastcgi_index     index.php;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include              fastcgi_params;
}
```

It would be nice if somebody could give me a basic run through of what the hell is going wrong.

Comment: Do you have file `helloworld.php`?

Comment: Hey, The idea is that we redirect to an index.php and then we have routes without any file extensions. However, we have a problem where we need to be able to redirect to a url that has the extension '.php'. For whatever reason this config isn't following the same rules as the other urls.

Comment: “Whatever reason” is `location ~* \.php$`.